# How does $2^{\aleph_2} \leqslant \aleph_{\omega}$ imply $\aleph_{\omega}^{\aleph_2} = \aleph_{\omega}^{\aleph_0}$?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I'm currently studying for my set theory exam and I got stuck trying to prove that if $2^{\aleph_2} \leqslant \aleph_{\omega}$ then $\aleph_{\omega}^{\aleph_2} = \aleph_{\omega}^{\aleph_0}$. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2601679/462